# Angular JS: How to call a function inside link from controller in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a custom directive that has a link and controller. The code is

```
  var delightMeterApp = angular.module('delightMeterApp', []);
    delightMeterApp.directive('delightMeter', function () {

        function link($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            document.getElementById("arc1").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -90, -56));
            document.getElementById("arc2").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -54, -20));
            document.getElementById("arc3").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -18, 16));
            document.getElementById("arc4").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 18, 52));
            document.getElementById("arc5").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 54, 90));

            function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
                var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

                return {
                    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
                    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
                };
            }

            function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {

                var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
                var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

                var arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

                var d = [
                    "M", start.x, start.y,
                    "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y
                ].join(" ");

                return d;
            }


            function ScoreRotateNeedle(delightScore) {

                $('.needleset').css({
                    "transform": "rotate(" + delightScore + "deg)",
                    "transform-origin": "50% 95%"
                });
            }

            $scope.$watch('score', function() {
                ScoreRotateNeedle($scope.score);
            });
        }
        return {
            scope: {
                score: '=ngModel'
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'svgmeter.html',
            link: link,
            controller: 'delightMeterController'

        };
    });


    delightMeterApp.controller('delightMeterController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.delightScore = 0;
        });
```

I want to call the `ScoreRotateNeedle` function which is inside the link from the controller. I call the function inside controller on `ng-change` event from my HTML like this.

```
<div ng-controller="delightMeterController">
    <delight-meter ng-model="delightScore"></delight-meter>
    <input id="txtScore" type="text" ng-model="delightScore" />{{delightScore}}

</div>
```

since it is not a good way to include DOM manipulations inside controller i want to have this function inside the link or elsewhere. How can i achieve this or should i use a service ?

Update:

```
<div id="delightmeter">


    <svg width='500px' height='300px' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>

        <g>
            <text x='100' y='220' fill='black'>0</text>
            <text x='300' y='220' fill='black'>100</text>
            <path class='arc' id='arc1' d='' />
            <path class='arc' id='arc2' d='' />
            <path class='arc' id='arc3' d='' />
            <path class='arc' id='arc4' d='' />
            <path class='arc' id='arc5' d='' />
            <g class='needleset'>
                <circle class='needle-center' cx='200' cy='200' r='5'></circle>
                <path class='needle' d='M 195 198 L 200 100 L 205 202'></path>
                <circle class='needle-center' cx='200' cy='200' r='5'></circle>
            </g>
        </g>

    </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Here is a working Plunker of the code http://plnkr.co/edit/tWeNjM0H7F6npc2mM9L2?p=preview

Comment: Well that works perfectly. Thanks for all your efforts. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="delightMeterController">
    <delightmeter ng-model="delightScore"></delightmeter>
    <input id="txtScore" type="text" ng-model="delightScore" />{{delightScore}}

</div>
```

Directive:

```
    .directive('delightmeter', function () {
    function link($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        var meter = $element[0];
        console.log(meter);

        document.getElementById("arc1").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -90, -56));
        document.getElementById("arc2").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -54, -20));
        document.getElementById("arc3").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, -18, 16));
        document.getElementById("arc4").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 18, 52));
        document.getElementById("arc5").setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 100, 54, 90));

        function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
            var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

            return {
                x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
                y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
            };
        }

        function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {

            var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
            var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);
            var arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";
            var d = [
                "M", start.x, start.y,
                "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y
            ].join(" ");
            return d;
        }

        function ScoreRotateNeedle(delightScore) {

            $('.needleset').css({
                "transform": "rotate(" + delightScore + "deg)",
                "transform-origin": "50% 95%"
            });
        }

        $scope.$watch('score', function() {
            ScoreRotateNeedle($scope.score);
        });
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'components/comp01/comp01.html',
        scope: {
            score: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: link
    };
})
```

Controller:

```
.controller('delightMeterController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.delightScore = 0;

})
```

Comment: To stick to the problem statement i can only have `ng-model` attribute in the custom HTML tag. I cannot use any other attributes.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same without that attribute?

Comment: You do not want to use the reference delightMeterReference?

Comment: No , i have to do it with `ng-model` alone

Comment: Updated the above answer with scope: { score: '=ngModel'} and $watching the score variable change - I have it working on my machine

Comment: The function is called anytime the value of ng-model on the directive (delightScore) changes. So you will not need to call the function manually

Comment: I have updated the question here and my code with your exact same code. Still not working. There are no console errors too.

Comment: Can you post the contents of svgmeter.html too

Comment: It has been added. Thanks for your precious time

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the `scope: true,` and bind the function to the scope.

Comment: Can you please add the syntax to call the function from the controller. I'm totally new to angular JS

Answer (score 1):

Use isolate-scope within the directive..

```
$scope.control.moveNeedle = function () {
$scope.ScoreRotateNeedle();
 }
return {
            scope: **{control: '='}**,
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'svgmeter.html',
            link: link,
            controller: 'delightMeterController'

        };
```

Add this code to your controller

```
$scope.ctrl = {};
```

in HTML use

```
<div ng-app="delightMeterApp" ng-controller="delightMeterController">
    <delight-meter ng-model="delightScore" control = "ctrl"></delight-meter>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" ng-model="delightScore" ng-change="ctrl.rotateNeedle()" />
</div>
```

Comment: How will i call the `ScoreRotateNeedle()` from the controller. Can you please show the syntax?
and what is the need of that `moveNeedle` function?

Comment: The function will get defined in the ctrl isolated scope by **control=="ctrl"**, so you can call the function using ctrl.moveNeedle(); in ng-change, for JS you can use $scope.ctrl.moveNeedle();  The moveNeedle function is created in the isolated scope, which can be called from the your main controller,